# Randomly choose rows of a two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a file contain 34 rows and 17 columns of data and I would like to choose 100 time one of the rows randomly and add to 17 components of the row different different noise values. What is the best way to choose completely randomly a row?

Comment: Can't you just generate a random number between 0 and 33 and use that as an index to your array?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module, use `random.choice`:

```
import random

nrows = 17
random_row_index = random.choice(range(nrows))
```